# In the proof that the power series ring of an integrally closed domain may not be integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I was reading exercise 27, Chapter V of Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra. The problem goes like this;

> Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain that is not completely integrally closed, $X$ an indeterminate of $R$ and $a$ a nonzero nonunit of $R$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}a^{i}R\neq 0$. Show that there exists an element $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}X^{n}$ of the quotient field of $R[[X]]$ such that $f^{2}-af+X=0$ but $f\not\in R[[X]]$, so $R[[X]]$ is not integrally closed.

My question is, can the assumption that $R$ is integrally closed be dropped? I do understand that we have to assume that $R$ is not completely integrally closed since such $a$ would not exist otherwise, but I cannot find where $R$ being integrally closed is needed in this proof.

Comment: Well, if the aim is to show that the power series ring of an integrally closed domain need not be integrally closed, you better start with an integrally closed domain. So maybe the essential point is that there exist integrally closed domains that are not completely integrally closed

Comment: So, I guess that the purpose of this exercise is to show that $R[[X]]$ may not be integrally closed even if $R$ is integrally closed, but even if $R$ is not integrally closed the conclusion is still true... Is it the case?